# How can I store a POJO in Redis with Micronaut framework?

Tags: java, redis, micronaut

I am new to Micronaut. I am trying to port a project to Micronaut (v1.1.1) and I have found a problem with Redis.

I am just trying to save a simple POJO in Redis, but when I try to "save" it the following error is raised:

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisException: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: Cannot encode command. Please close the connection as the connection state may be out of sync.
```

Code is very simple ([HERE](https://gist.github.com/jlojosnegros/ebcc51255796e4aee1d1a460023fe5cf) you can find a complete test.):

```java
class DummyTest {
  @Test
  public void testIssue() throws Exception {

    final Date now = Date.from(Instant.now());
    CatalogContent expectedContentOne = CatalogContent.builder()
            .contentId(1)
            .status(ContentStatus.AVAILABLE)
            .title("uno")
            .streamId(1)
            .available(now)
            .tags(Set.of("tag1", "tag2"))
            .build();
    repository.save(expectedContentOne);
  }
}
  /.../

class CatalogContentRepository {
    private StatefulRedisConnection<String, CatalogContent> connection;

    public CatalogContentRepository(StatefulRedisConnection<String, CatalogContent> connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    } 
    public void save(CatalogContent content) {
        RedisCommands<String, CatalogContent> redisApi = connection.sync();
        redisApi.set(String.valueOf(content.getContentId()),content); //Error here!
    }
}
```

Any idea will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For the record I will answer my own question:

Right now (20190514) Micronaut only generate `StatefulRedisConnection<String,String>` with a hardcoded UTF8 String codec. 
To change this you have to replace the `DefaultRedisClientFactory` and define a method returning the `StatefulRedisConnection` you need,
with your prefered codec.

In my case:

```java
@Requires(beans = DefaultRedisConfiguration.class)
@Singleton
@Factory
@Replaces(factory = DefaultRedisClientFactory.class)
public class RedisClientFactory extends AbstractRedisClientFactory {

  @Bean(preDestroy = "shutdown")
  @Singleton
  @Primary
  @Override
  public RedisClient redisClient(@Primary AbstractRedisConfiguration config) {
    return super.redisClient(config);
  }


  @Bean(preDestroy = "close")
  @Singleton
  @Primary
  public StatefulRedisConnection<String, Object> myRedisConnection(@Primary RedisClient redisClient) {
    return redisClient.connect(new SerializedObjectCodec());
  }

  @Bean(preDestroy = "close")
  @Singleton
  @Primary
  @Override
  public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection(@Primary RedisClient redisClient) {
    throw new RuntimeException("puta mierda");
  }


  @Override
  @Bean(preDestroy = "close")
  @Singleton
  public StatefulRedisPubSubConnection<String, String> redisPubSubConnection(@Primary RedisClient redisClient) {
    return super.redisPubSubConnection(redisClient);
  }
}
```

Codec has been taken from [Redis Lettuce wiki](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Codecs)

```java
public class SerializedObjectCodec implements RedisCodec<String, Object> {
  private Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

  @Override
  public String decodeKey(ByteBuffer bytes) {
    return charset.decode(bytes).toString();
  }

  @Override
  public Object decodeValue(ByteBuffer bytes) {
    try {
      byte[] array = new byte[bytes.remaining()];
      bytes.get(array);
      ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
      return is.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ByteBuffer encodeKey(String key) {
    return charset.encode(key);
  }

  @Override
  public ByteBuffer encodeValue(Object value) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bytes);
      os.writeObject(value);
      return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```